# How to center the contents of a UIWebView on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, center

I have a map image in a `UIWebView`.  It default loads in the top left hand corner.  I would like it to initialize in the center of the `UIWebView`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the map image is the only thing in the page, is it wrapped in an html page?  If it is at least wrapped in a body tag you could do the following:

```
NSString *bodyStyle = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.textAlign = 'center';";
NSString *mapStyle = @"document.getElementById('mapid').style.margin = 'auto';";

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyle];
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:mapStyle];
```

Let me know how exactly your html is structured and then I can provide some more information if necessary.

Comment: However it's displayed, the easiest (and pretty much only) way to interface with a UIWebView is through javascript

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is to just wrap your content in a `center-aligned` div tag.

```
<body>
<div align="center">
<!-- Your map here -->
</div>
</body>
```

This will work for your solution as long as you are fine with modifying the html that you pass through to the `UIWebView`. It doesn't require any javascript calls. The above solution, however, is needed if you'd prefer to inject style-sheet updates on demand and after the web page has loaded.